# Aligning a system of equations

Tags: align

I am trying to align three equations in two lines. How can I do it using \begin{align*}?

I want it to look like this:

[image]

But mine looks like this:

[image]

My code:

```
\begin{align*}
A^2 &= A, B^2 &= C, C^2 &= B,\\
AB &= B, AC &= C, BC &=A, 
\end{align*}
```

Comment: you need to indicate a column break after each comma, and add space there as well.

Comment: In short: `n` alignment groups require  `2n - 1` ampersands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick fix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 \begin{align*}
   A^2 &= A, & B^2 &= C, & C^2 &= B,\\
   AB &= B, & AC &= C, & BC &= A,
 \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{4} A^2 &= A, & \quad & B^2 &= C, &\quad& C^2 &= B,\\AB &= B,&& AC &= C,&& BC &= A, \end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without "alignat"?

Comment: @user19405892 there is also `alignedat` inside `equation*` or just `array` or a `table` or `minipage`s. If you have some restrictions, you should tell us before and explain why!